# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException using GSON

Tags: android, json, android-studio, gson

I am parsing my Server's response using GSON. But, getting

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException

Currently i am sending hardcoded JSON. Removed all Boolean, Float values etc. Currently i am parsing String values only.

**LoginPOJO.java**

```
package com.chsoneresidential.chsone.pojo;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

/**
 * Created by pawan on 24/10/16.
 */
public class LoginPOJO {

    //High priority variables goes below.....
    @SerializedName("version")
    private String version;

    @SerializedName("app")
    private String app;

//    @SerializedName("error")
//    private String error;

    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;

    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;

    @SerializedName("access_token")
    private String access_token;

    @SerializedName("token_type")
    private String token_type;

//    @SerializedName("expires")
//    private String expires;

//    @SerializedName("expires_in")
//    private String expires_in;

    @SerializedName("refresh_token")
    private String refresh_token;

    @SerializedName("user_id")
    private String user_id;

    @SerializedName("role")
    private String role;

    @SerializedName("user_name")
    private String user_name;

    @SerializedName("soc_id")
    private String soc_id;

    @SerializedName("user_first_name")
    private String user_first_name;

    @SerializedName("user_last_name")
    private String user_last_name;

    @SerializedName("user_email_id")
    private String user_email_id;

    @SerializedName("user_mobile_number")
    private String user_mobile_number;

    @SerializedName("user_dob")
    private String user_dob;

    @SerializedName("user_profile_photo")
    private String user_profile_photo;

}//LoginPOJO closes here....
```

My Activity where i am getting response:

```
@Override
    public void networkResponseSuccess(String response) {
        Log.d(TAG, "networkResponseSuccess: "+response);

        try{
            Gson gson = new Gson();

//            LoginPOJO loginPOJO = gson.fromJson(reader, Staff.class);
            LoginPOJO loginPOJO = gson.fromJson("{\n" +
                    "\t\"app\": {\n" +
                    "\t\t\"version\": \"v1.0\",\n" +
                    "\t\t\"app\": \"CHSONE\"\n" +
                    "\t},\n" +
                    "\t\"status\": \"OK\",\n" +
                    "\t\"message\": \"Welcome\",\n" +
                    "\t\"data\": {\n" +
                    "\t\t\"access_info\": {\n" +
                    "\t\t\t\"access_token\": \"OWcbj51uCe2SLQt7ad3XjUKRUawWMoUSvjSLPMVJ\",\n" +
                    "\t\t\t\"token_type\": \"Bearer\",\n" +
                    "\t\t\t\"refresh_token\": \"Bto2r5LkGdHNsYydUzi1Zj02aUl3J1CazZJ2g3F0\"\n" +
                    "\t\t},\n" +
                    "\t\t\"user_data\": {\n" +
                    "\t\t\t\"user_id\": \"803\",\n" +
                    "\t\t\t\"role\": \"admin,member\",\n" +
                    "\t\t\t\"user_name\": \"virajk123456\",\n" +
                    "\t\t\t\"soc_id\": \"846\",\n" +
                    "\t\t\t\"user_first_name\": \"Viraj\",\n" +
                    "\t\t\t\"user_last_name\": \"kaulkar\",\n" +
                    "\t\t\t\"user_email_id\": \"viraj@futurescape.co.in\",\n" +
                    "\t\t\t\"user_mobile_number\": \"8828162613\",\n" +
                    "\t\t\t\"user_dob\": \"1987-09-10\",\n" +
                    "\t\t\t\"user_profile_photo\": \"dev.chsone.in.s3.amazonaws.com\\/846\\/avatar\\/803\\/avtar_803.jpg\"\n" +
                    "\t\t}\n" +
                    "\t}\n" +
                    "}", LoginPOJO.class);
            System.out.println(loginPOJO);





        }//try closes here....
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "networkResponseSuccess: Exception = "+e);
        }//catch closes here.....
```

**LOGCAT WHERE IA M GETTING JSON SYNTAX EXCEPTION:**

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 2 column 10 path $.app com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:773)
at com.chsoneresidential.chsone.LoginActivity.networkResponseSuccess(LoginActivity.java:166)
at com.chsoneresidential.chsone.network.NetworkResponseHandler.onResponse(NetworkResponseHandler.java:139)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:67)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 2 column 10 path $.app
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextString(JsonReader.java:825)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$16.read(TypeAdapters.java:418)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$16.read(TypeAdapters.java:406)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
... 18 more
```

Comment: Please learn some JSON basics ... it is not "flat object" ... it has nested objects too, fx "app" and "access_token" are not in the same object ...

Comment: *I know JSOn* ... no, you don't ... "app" is not a string ... at the "first level" you have only 4 properties ...

Comment: As mentioned, your LoginPOJO object is incorrect. Try using [this website](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to generate your model classes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code for parsing your json:

```
public class Example {

@SerializedName("app")
@Expose
private App app;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private Data data;

/**
* 
* @return
* The app
*/
public App getApp() {
return app;
}

/**
* 
* @param app
* The app
*/
public void setApp(App app) {
this.app = app;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The status
*/
public String getStatus() {
return status;
}

/**
* 
* @param status
* The status
*/
public void setStatus(String status) {
this.status = status;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The message
*/
public String getMessage() {
return message;
}

/**
* 
* @param message
* The message
*/
public void setMessage(String message) {
this.message = message;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The data
*/
public Data getData() {
return data;
}

/**
* 
* @param data
* The data
*/
public void setData(Data data) {
this.data = data;
}

}

public class App {

@SerializedName("version")
@Expose
private String version;
@SerializedName("app")
@Expose
private String app;

/**
* 
* @return
* The version
*/
public String getVersion() {
return version;
}

/**
* 
* @param version
* The version
*/
public void setVersion(String version) {
this.version = version;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The app
*/
public String getApp() {
return app;
}

/**
* 
* @param app
* The app
*/
public void setApp(String app) {
this.app = app;
}

}

public class Data {

@SerializedName("access_info")
@Expose
private AccessInfo accessInfo;
@SerializedName("user_data")
@Expose
private UserData userData;

/**
* 
* @return
* The accessInfo
*/
public AccessInfo getAccessInfo() {
return accessInfo;
}

/**
* 
* @param accessInfo
* The access_info
*/
public void setAccessInfo(AccessInfo accessInfo) {
this.accessInfo = accessInfo;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The userData
*/
public UserData getUserData() {
return userData;
}

/**
* 
* @param userData
* The user_data
*/
public void setUserData(UserData userData) {
this.userData = userData;
}

}

public class AccessInfo {

@SerializedName("access_token")
@Expose
private String accessToken;
@SerializedName("token_type")
@Expose
private String tokenType;
@SerializedName("refresh_token")
@Expose
private String refreshToken;

/**
* 
* @return
* The accessToken
*/
public String getAccessToken() {
return accessToken;
}

/**
* 
* @param accessToken
* The access_token
*/
public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
this.accessToken = accessToken;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The tokenType
*/
public String getTokenType() {
return tokenType;
}

/**
* 
* @param tokenType
* The token_type
*/
public void setTokenType(String tokenType) {
this.tokenType = tokenType;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The refreshToken
*/
public String getRefreshToken() {
return refreshToken;
}

/**
* 
* @param refreshToken
* The refresh_token
*/
public void setRefreshToken(String refreshToken) {
this.refreshToken = refreshToken;
}

}

public class UserData {

@SerializedName("user_id")
@Expose
private String userId;
@SerializedName("role")
@Expose
private String role;
@SerializedName("user_name")
@Expose
private String userName;
@SerializedName("soc_id")
@Expose
private String socId;
@SerializedName("user_first_name")
@Expose
private String userFirstName;
@SerializedName("user_last_name")
@Expose
private String userLastName;
@SerializedName("user_email_id")
@Expose
private String userEmailId;
@SerializedName("user_mobile_number")
@Expose
private String userMobileNumber;
@SerializedName("user_dob")
@Expose
private String userDob;
@SerializedName("user_profile_photo")
@Expose
private String userProfilePhoto;

/**
* 
* @return
* The userId
*/
public String getUserId() {
return userId;
}

/**
* 
* @param userId
* The user_id
*/
public void setUserId(String userId) {
this.userId = userId;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The role
*/
public String getRole() {
return role;
}

/**
* 
* @param role
* The role
*/
public void setRole(String role) {
this.role = role;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The userName
*/
public String getUserName() {
return userName;
}

/**
* 
* @param userName
* The user_name
*/
public void setUserName(String userName) {
this.userName = userName;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The socId
*/
public String getSocId() {
return socId;
}

/**
* 
* @param socId
* The soc_id
*/
public void setSocId(String socId) {
this.socId = socId;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The userFirstName
*/
public String getUserFirstName() {
return userFirstName;
}

/**
* 
* @param userFirstName
* The user_first_name
*/
public void setUserFirstName(String userFirstName) {
this.userFirstName = userFirstName;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The userLastName
*/
public String getUserLastName() {
return userLastName;
}

/**
* 
* @param userLastName
* The user_last_name
*/
public void setUserLastName(String userLastName) {
this.userLastName = userLastName;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The userEmailId
*/
public String getUserEmailId() {
return userEmailId;
}

/**
* 
* @param userEmailId
* The user_email_id
*/
public void setUserEmailId(String userEmailId) {
this.userEmailId = userEmailId;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The userMobileNumber
*/
public String getUserMobileNumber() {
return userMobileNumber;
}

/**
* 
* @param userMobileNumber
* The user_mobile_number
*/
public void setUserMobileNumber(String userMobileNumber) {
this.userMobileNumber = userMobileNumber;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The userDob
*/
public String getUserDob() {
return userDob;
}

/**
* 
* @param userDob
* The user_dob
*/
public void setUserDob(String userDob) {
this.userDob = userDob;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The userProfilePhoto
*/
public String getUserProfilePhoto() {
return userProfilePhoto;
}

/**
* 
* @param userProfilePhoto
* The user_profile_photo
*/
public void setUserProfilePhoto(String userProfilePhoto) {
this.userProfilePhoto = userProfilePhoto;
}

}
```